# How to change the order in which elements load on homepage?

Tags: html, blogger

[image]

For some reason my blog homepage starts loading half way down the page, and then slides to the top when the featured images above it have loaded. I'm not sure why it's doing this. Does anyone know how I can change the order so it loads from the first element at the top of the page?

Link to blog is: https://futuremag-demo.blogspot.com

Comment: The site can’t be reached

Comment: It works fine for me @ShadiNamrouti 

Comment: I just tried it and it worked without any problems, it looked all fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The featured post section requires JavaScript to render but currently that Javascript is executed only after all the HTML is loaded on the page (likely to prevent render blocking issues).

Currently `<span data-type="recent"></span>` is the only HTML present in the HTML/Javascript widget which renders the featured post section. Behind the scenes, when JavaScript detects the above HTML, it makes an Ajax call to the specific Blogger feed (`/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=4`) to get the posts to be shown in that section.

One way to resolve this problem is by moving the JS snippet responsible for rendering this featured section just after the HTML `<span data-type="recent"></span>` present in the widget. The specific JS snippet responsible for this section is -

```
<script>
$('.featured .HTML .widget-content').each(function() {
    var v = $(this).find("span").attr("data-label"),
        box = $(this).find("span").attr("data-type");
    if (box.match('recent')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=4",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(e) {
                var u = "";
                var h = '<ul>';
                for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < e.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                        if (e.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                            u = e.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    var g = e.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
                    var s = e.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
                    var y = e.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
                    var d = e.feed.entry[i].published.$t,
                        t = d.substring(0, 4),
                        w = d.substring(5, 7),
                        f = d.substring(8, 10),
                        r = month_format[parseInt(w, 10)] + ' ' + f + ', ' + t;
                    var c = e.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
                    var $c = $('<div>').html(c);
                    if (c.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/") > -1) {
                        var p = e.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                        var k = p
                    } else if (c.indexOf("<img") > -1) {
                        var q = $c.find('img:first').attr('src');
                        var k = q
                    } else {
                        var k = no_image
                    }
                    h += '<li><div class="featured-inner"><a href="/search/label/' + s + '" class="post-tag icon ' + s + '">' + s + '</a><a class="rcp-thumb" href="' + u + '" style="background:url(' + k + ') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="featured-overlay"/></a><div class="post-panel"><h3 class="rcp-title"><a href="' + u + '">' + g + '</a></h3><div class="featured-meta"><span class="featured-author idel">' + y + '</span><span class="featured-date">' + r + '</span></div></div></div></li>'
                }
                h += '</ul>';
                $(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function() {
                    $(this).html(h);
                    $(this).find('.rcp-thumb').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                            return src.replace('/default.jpg', '/mqdefault.jpg')
                        }).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                            return src.replace('s72-c', 's1600')
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    } else if (box.match('label')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + v + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=4",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(e) {
                var u = "";
                var h = '<ul>';
                for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < e.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                        if (e.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                            u = e.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    var g = e.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
                    var s = e.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
                    var y = e.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
                    var d = e.feed.entry[i].published.$t,
                        t = d.substring(0, 4),
                        w = d.substring(5, 7),
                        f = d.substring(8, 10),
                        r = month_format[parseInt(w, 10)] + ' ' + f + ', ' + t;
                    var c = e.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
                    var $c = $('<div>').html(c);
                    if (c.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/") > -1) {
                        var p = e.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                        var k = p
                    } else if (c.indexOf("<img") > -1) {
                        var q = $c.find('img:first').attr('src');
                        var k = q
                    } else {
                        var k = no_image
                    }
                    h += '<li><div class="featured-inner"><a href="/search/label/' + s + '" class="post-tag icon ' + s + '">' + s + '</a><a class="rcp-thumb" href="' + u + '" style="background:url(' + k + ') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="featured-overlay"/></a><div class="post-panel"><h3 class="rcp-title"><a href="' + u + '">' + g + '</a></h3><div class="featured-meta"><span class="featured-author idel">' + y + '</span><span class="featured-date">' + r + '</span></div></div></div></li>'
                }
                h += '</ul>';
                $(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function() {
                    $(this).html(h);
                    $(this).find('.rcp-thumb').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                            return src.replace('/default.jpg', '/mqdefault.jpg')
                        }).attr('style', function(i, src) {
                            return src.replace('s72-c', 's1600')
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Prayag, I removed the JavaScript from the bottom and pasted it just after the code you said, but there was a problem with it. I have added a screen shot of the result in the post above. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Also, @PrayagVerma, is there a way I can just remove the AJAX call?

Comment: The issue shown in the above screenshot is happening because the code is directly added without enclosing it in `script` tags. Use the updated code snippet and then see if things work. Regarding the AJAX call, that cannot be removed because the posts keep on changing. If you remove the AJAX call and add the content manually for the first time, then when the content is updated going forward, you will have to change the post each time

Comment: Thanks @Prayag. It worked, and my blog is loading slightly quicker, although the blog feed is still loading first. Do you know another way to have the featured post section load first so the screen doesn't have to slide up?

Comment: That would require rewriting the above code to be render blocking in nature (using something like document.write) but I would recommend against that (Refer to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/document-write). A different approach would be to use CSS to set a `min-height` for the container of the featured post section so that it appears empty initially until the content is loaded. This would prevent the sudden jerk that currently happens when the AJAX call gets completed. You would have to take into account the responsive breakpoints for creating the new CSS rules

Comment: Thank you so much @Prayag :) The min-height makes it look much better!

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the website, it's found that the said images have big sizes which makes them load slowly.

They can be compressed using a technique called [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) to minimize the size without distorting the resolution of the image.

Compress your images using (for example): https://compressjpeg.com/
and test again.

Comment: Thanks Shadi, I will try that!